# Add conditions into .env file in reactjs. I have .env file in my reactJS project. Is it possible to do if/else conditions into this file?

Tags: reactjs

> SSL= ${process.env.SSL} || false
> protocol = SSL ? 'https' : 'http'
> REACT_APP_SERVER_URL=${protocol}://api/logistics

Comment: What are you aiming for?
Creating some different setups for dev / production, or something else?

Comment: Yes I have separate .env files for prod, Dev, and UAT.. but I'm trying make some conditions for protocols

Comment: Did u get how to do it?